# Set max-width of element based on sibling using flexbox

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a layout for a thumbnails component which contains an image and text element. The images have a `height: 100px;` and auto width, while the text should span up to the width of the image width and the overflow should be hidden.

```
<div>
    <img src="...">
    <span>a bunch of text that should be cut off</span>
</div>
```

I've tried accomplishing this using flexbox but I can't get the text width to be equal to the image width. Instead, the text just grows 100% and stretches out the image.

[See my jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qunupavagi/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to specify container's width -> so that your text box knows it's width.
2. You need tell text to not wrap.
3. You need to hide the overflowing text.
4. You need ellipsis for overflowing text.

---

Following code works:

```css
.main {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 50%; // px would also work
}
.main img {
  height: 100px;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
.main div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/uiGur1h.jpg" alt="">
  <div>Text go here </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/uiGur1h.jpg" alt="">
  <div>Text would go here but would be cut off if it's very long </div>
</div>
```

---

Refer example in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow